# Mdanter GmpMath::cmp() must be instance of GMP

Tags: php, rpc, bitcoin, gmp, bitcoin-testnet

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Mdanter\Ecc\Math\GmpMath::cmp() must be an instance of GMP, string
>   given, called in
>   /var/www/html/btc/lib/vendor/bitwasp/bitcoin/src/Crypto/EcAdapter/BaseEcAdapter.php
>   on line 64 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/btc/lib/vendor/mdanter/ecc/src/Math/GmpMath.php:13\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/btc/lib/vendor/bitwasp/bitcoin/src/Crypto/EcAdapter/BaseEcAdapter.php(64):
>   Mdanter\Ecc\Math\GmpMath->cmp('105825702696369...',
>   Object(GMP))\n#1
>   /var/www/html/btc/lib/vendor/bitwasp/bitcoin/src/Crypto/EcAdapter/PhpEcc.php(220):
>   BitWasp\Bitcoin\Crypto\EcAdapter\BaseEcAdapter->checkInt('105825702696369...',
>   Object(GMP))\n#2
>   /var/www/html/btc/lib/vendor/bitwasp/bitcoin/src/Key/PrivateKey.php(44):
>   BitWasp\Bitcoin\Crypto\EcAdapter\PhpEcc->validatePrivateKey(Object(BitWasp\Buffertools\Buffer))\n#3
>   /var/www/html/btc/lib/vendor/bitwasp/bitcoin/src/Key/PrivateKeyFactory.php(43):
>   BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKey->__construct(Object(BitWasp\Bitcoin\Crypto\EcAdapter\PhpEcc),
>   '105825702696369...', false) in
>   /var/www/html/btc/lib/vendor/mdanter/ecc/src/Math/GmpMath.php on line
>   13

The bitwasp is giving a string output instead of GMP object while creating public key

Answer (score 0):

Change the BITWASP to rpc-bitcoin for a good and handy access to bitcoin noce